# jQuery get CSS value of div with percentage

Tags: jquery, html

This might seem a dumb question but how do I get the CSS value of an element that is a percentage? e.g.

```
if ($('#main_element').css('left') == '-100%') {
    alert('position is negative');
});
```

This doesn't seem to do anything even though the element is positioned left -100%

Thanks

Comment: you can't get css in percentage, but you can get it manually by reading its parent width and doing some calculation from it.

Comment: Can I get the value in pixels then?